# Asking about phrase type

Tags: adjective-phrases

‎In a noun phrase “billions of dollars’ worth of satellites”
Is “billions of dollars’ worth of” an adjective phrase that modifies ‘satellites’?

Comment: The alternative would be to parse it as referring to some plural entity identified as **dollars’ worth of satellites**, which is so numerous there are ***billions*** of them.

Comment: See [What is the main noun in “a year's worth of learning” in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113552/what-is-the-main-noun-in-a-years-worth-of-learning-in-the-following-sentence)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the main noun in "a year's worth of learning" in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113552/what-is-the-main-noun-in-a-years-worth-of-learning-in-the-following-sentence)

Comment: No: "billion's of dollars’ worth of" is not a constituent. "Billions of dollars' worth" is a nominal (not an NP) with "worth" as head. "Of satellites" is a PP with "of" as head, the PP functioning as complement of "worth".