# structure of ‘worth of’

Tags: syntax, parsing

1. Is “billions of dollars worth of satellites” (without an apostrophe after dollars) grammatically incorrect?
2. In the fragment “billions of dollars’ worth of”, is my analysis of the syntax (below) correct?

- [billions of dollars] : noun phrase
- [billions of dollars]’ : determiner of ‘worth’ = adjective phrase

Comment: I answered your second question here: [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278638/asking-about-phrase-type#comment520460_278638)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking about phrase type](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278638/asking-about-phrase-type)

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe is required for the sentence to be correct. See [this English.stackexchange answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/118151) and [this blog post](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/05/genitively-speaking.html) for more details. The upshot is that "billions of dollars'" is in the genitive, *i.e.* possessive, case—so it needs an apostrophe.

Comment: The thing that belongs to the billions of dollars is the worth?